# Putting 了 in both parts of separable verbs: is it mandatory?

Tags: sentence-structure

My sentence is

> 我们八点已经开始上了课。

**Can I put 了 at the end of sentence? Or is it mandatory to put between both parts of 上课 (a separable verb)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

开始上了课 is not grammatical. 开始 means 'started', 上了课 means 'have finished class', You cannot "Started to have finished class"

A  grammatical sentence should be 我早上上课 (I attend classes in the morning) --> 我早上上了课 (I have attended classes in the morning)

And yes, you can insert 了 between the verb and noun in any separable verb to indicate it is completed action

Example:

看書 (read book) --> 看了書 (have read book)

吃飯 (eat meal) --> 吃了飯 (have eaten meal)

逃學 (skip classes) --> 逃了學 (have skipped classes)

Comment: But I wonder if under any circumstances, 了 must be inserted between Verb and Object in separable verbs, right?

Comment: 看过书, 吃过饭, 逃过学 = had read book, had eaten meal, had skipped classes . 过 as a aspect marker indicates the verb is "experienced"

Answer (score 0):

I would not say 上了课 means 'have finished class'。

你已经开始上课了吗？
Have you started your classes?

约翰，你的同学已经在上课了。
John, your classmates are already starting class.

他上了课也做了他应该做的。
He attended classes and did what he should.

我们八点就已经开始上课了。
At 8 o'clock we already begin class.

我们已经上完课。
We've already finished class.

我们已经下了课。
我们已经下课了。
We've already finished class.

我昨天上了课了。
I went to class yesterday.

Often, 下了课 indicates a time in the future:

好吧，下了课之后我们去学生中心休息一下。
OK, after class let's go to the student centre and relax.